# spec ip and spec vp

Tags: syntax, x-bar-theory

I'm new to linguistics. I'm reading an article saying that
"Subjects of stage-level predicates can be mapped into either [Spec,IP] or [Spec,VP]. Subjects of individual level predicates must stay in [Spec,VP]". So may I ask what are Spec,IP and Spec,VP. Thank you

Comment: The specifier position of the IP and VP phrases.